# Did anyone succeed to use the RotarySelector (Lockscreen slider to unlock) in an app?

Tags: android, widget

The android lockscreen widget that use 2 buttons that we can swipe from right to left or left to right is really cool!

Unfortunately, that's not a public one, it his hidden in android.internal stuff...

I really would like to use it and tried to use the same source code than Android: http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/RotarySelector.java.shtml

Unfortunately, a lot of things are related to internal and some variables (mRight) cannot be found and are not declared.

Also I am missing 2 files:
R.styleable.RotarySelector and R.styleable.RotarySelector_orientation

I cannot believe nobody succeed to use this cool stuff!

Any idea or link to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently porting ICS NumberPicker and it took me a while to realize where mRight, mLeft... where coming from.. they come from View (which is like 3 classes up in the hierarchy).

To get those values you can use their corresponding public methods:

- [getRight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRight%28%29)
- [getLeft()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29)
- [getTop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29)
- [getBottom()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBottom%28%29)
- [getHeight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29)
- [getWidth()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29)
- [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29)

As for R stuff check the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/values), you may need values from attr.xml, styles.xml and themes.xml